# How to select databases based on users access to allowed databases?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a following command that executes when you log in as administrator with windows authentication right to SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
var sqlAdapter = 
    new SqlDataAdapter(@"select dtb.name as [Name],
                                CAST(case when dtb.name in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') then 1 
                                          else dtb.is_distributor end AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject]
                         from model.sys.databases dtb", connection);
sqlAdapter.Fill(table);
```

But when I try to log in as datareader which has only sp_datareader permissions I get an exception:

> *The server principal "datareader" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context.*

Now is there a way to check user permissions before creating adapter? For example if a user has only access to specific database or databases only display(or load) those databases? And if user has full permissions then execute command for adapter that I wrote here.
If my question is not understood so easily please tell me I'll try to clarify it as much as possible.

Thank you

Comment: You aren't trying to connect to the "model" database though are you?

Comment: You can just wrap it up with `try..catch` block.

Comment: Guess I'll actually read the query next time before commenting.  As Shadow Wizard commented, you can wrap your code in a try/catch.  In fact, you could first wrap a test query in a try/catch to first determine permissions, then branch accordingly.  However, I am curious as to why you are querying the model database in the first place.

Comment: No I am not trying to connect. I did wrap it with try catch but that is not solving the problem since I need to load the right database, actually the database that datareader has access to it(I've enabled datareader user to have access to one database, called Test);

Answer (score 0):

The user need to have "**db_datareader**" rights for your database (model) under "**User Mapping**".

*Security*->*Logins*->right click "*datareader*" (your user) -> *Properties* -> *User Mappings*

Select the database (model in your case) and then down below check the db_datareader role.

Comment: Yes, that worked but I still need to load only those databases that this user is having access. Like I said he has access to database Test, so I need to load that database. And in case there are more then one database that datareader is having access how to load them all? With that command that I wrote up for dataadapter all databases are loaded which is great when that user is having access to them all but in case of datareader I only need those databases that datareader has access to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've changed the command to be like this:

```
select dtb.name as [Name],
CAST(case when dtb.name in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') then 1 
else dtb.is_distributor end AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject]
from sys.databases dtb
```

Removed model and now it's only sys.databases. This is working since I don't have to go and do user mapping on model now. But still it would be great to have a query that can return only databases that current user has permissions.

Comment: and then just added were has_dbaccess (dtb.name) = 1